# PCBSim for Autodesk Eagle Alternatives

Tags: simulation, eaglecad

I've just starting learning electronics.  I've been using Autodesk Eagle for a little while now since it runs on Linux and seems to be pretty full featured.  I like that you can easily design a circuit schema, layout PCB, and then order the PCB and parts. However, it seems to be missing a simulator which I really need.  Searching online it seems that there an add-on simulator called [PCBSim](http://felicitas-ce.de/product/pcbsim/).  It looks very cool, but the pricing is very high and as a hobbyist, I just cannot afford it.

Does Autodesk Eagle have any other, more moderately priced, add-on simulators?
Did I miss anything with Autodesk Eagle's built-in functionality when it comes to circuit simulation?  Should I be looking at other options other then Eagle?  I've tried running LTSpice via wine, but it's been buggy.

Thank you

Comment: I think you are unnecessarily limiting yourself by requiring an Eagle add-on (I also think you're limiting yourself with Eagle, but that's another matter). While it may not integrate as well with Eagle, LTSpice is free and generally well-liked by the community. What are you simulating? There may be other more appropriate options.

Comment: Hi, I need something that can run on Linux.  I've tried running LTSpice via wine, but it seems a little buggy.  Are there other options I should be looking at?

Comment: ngspice is probably the most commonly used native Linux simulator, but it's not quite as friendly as LTSpice IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run Wine 1.6.2 /LTSpice May 26 2016 /Ubuntu 16.04 and it's usable. There are minor GUI annoyances and I can't easily plot the current in a wire, but otherwise I can manage.  It might be worthwhile trying to address the Wine issues directly, rather than looking elsewhere for a simulator.

Can I suggest dropping Eagle?  Go for [Kicad](https://www.kicad.org/).  If it's good enough to design the Hadron Collider on, it should do for users here.  And they're starting to develop Spice integration too, but for free.

Comment: +1 for LTSpice + Kicad. Eagle licensing is only getting pricier/less functional under Autodesk, and Kicad is more capable with better community support.

Comment: @uint128_t To be honest, I view Autodesk as a danger to the free market with the rate they're buying up stuff. Their portfolio is huge. If they buy Dassault Systèmes and /or SolidWorks there'll be nothing left of the market.

Comment: I would agree with that. The real shame is that Sparkfun, Adafruit, and other "maker-friendly" shops have now designed themselves into a corner: they've got all their part libraries and boards in Eagle, and to redo all that would be too much. IMO, it's crippling the maker/DIY community.